# Mandarin movie about alien stone that speaks with a girl and they protect the girl

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a Mandarin movie about an alien stone that can speak with a girl and they protect the girl. I think the movie was in the 80s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a live-action movie, or animated?  Where did you see it?  Can you describe any of the characters?  What was the setting?

Comment: Who are the "they" that protect the girl?